# Is it possible to assign different encoders for android chromecast app?

Tags: chromecast, encoder

For Chromecast app in android devices, how do I know which encoder it will use while casting my mobile device (for example, nexus 5 or 9) to a big screen?

And is it possible to assign different encoders (or even HW/SW encoders) as I want?

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean decoder or encoder? Your stream is most likely already encoded so what do you mean by deciding what encoder? If you mean decoder, it is not the job of sender to do that, your receiver needs to decide how to handle the media. In your receiver, you can do anything you want and if desired, you can inform your senders (by broadcasting a message to them) about what you are doing in the receiver.

If you need to see what media formats are supported by Chromecast and MPL, take a look at our docs.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I did check your documents for all supported media formats.    Now what I want to do is to measure how different the performance could be by using different Codecs. I think switching to different encoder might be the first step.    Is it possible to do that switching?

Comment: No, it is not possible and please stop asking the same question here, in the G+ community and on other StackOverflow post at the same time; ask a question once and in one place not in three different places.

Comment: Sorry for my multiple asking, and I will continue here only.  According to the document of chromecast, it supports several media formats of video codecs: H.264 High Profile Level 4.1, 4.2, 5, and VP8.
Then how can I know which one it adopts while casting?

Comment: Are you talking about screen mirroring or normal casting?

Comment: I care both, and slightly more about screen mirroring. Probably I shall ask the question like this:  (1) [screen mirroring] is there a default selection of codec among those codecs? How would that selection been made? (2) [screen mirroring] Will chromecast switch to another one from the default codec? if yes, when and how?   ....

Comment: (3) [normal casting] I made some tests with different applications, the behaviors were slightly different. For example, casting a youtube video from android phone, the chromecast will fetch the video stream by it self and can be controlled by the mobile phone, at this moment I guess there is no media stream encoding from android phone to chromecast; but if casting a web page with text and pictures, there should be media encoding/decoding between phone and chromecast, is the codec in this scenario the same as screen mirroring?

Comment: (4) I tried to search source codes related to chromecast and I only find this: https://code.google.com/p/chromecast-mirrored-source/, is this the correct one for screen mirroring? May we download source codes for google cast app and chromecast dongle to comppile them...?

Comment: (1)For screen mirroring, there is nothing for you to configure or access, no api and nothing of that sort, so there is no public documentation around that.
(2) See (1).
(3) You cannot cast a web page; you can send only the URL of a web page and if your receiver tries to open that page, t is just a chrome browser opening a web page.
(4) You do not have access to the chromecast source to compile; it is not an open source project.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all explanations! //  just confused about (3): do you mean even if I open a web page with only text, when I press cast button on chrome browser, the extension in chrome browser only send the URL to chromecast dongle? And in this situation, the chromecast dongle "open" that text web page by itself independently and output the page to a big screen?..... My understanding and experience in tests is that the page in chrome browser was captured then encoded as a media stream and sent to chromecast dongle.

Comment: Currently what I'm trying to figure out is just happened inside between google cast extension in chrome browser and that chromecast dongle connected to a big screen.... I might move to develop my own sender and receiver, but I guess I still can not manipulate Codecs even if I have my own sender/receiver...:(

Comment: (sorry I have only 1 reputation which is not enough to move this discussion to a chat)...  Actually I have some other questions about chromecast streaming protocol stack: (for screen mirroring) is the media stream over udp or tcp? what about normal casting (if the answer to my previous question is yes there are media streams between sender extension and chromecast dongle as receiver)? ....Is it also impossible for me to assign tcp if udp is actually used for media stream transmission?

Comment: Regarding your confusion on (3), you had marked that as "normal cast". If you are referring to casting a web page from chrome browser, then that falls under mirroring (screen casting) and is not a normal cast. I am not clear why you need to know about the details of the protocol that is internally used for screen mirroring, it is not something you can influence through APIs, or change its configuration; it is happening internally so what is the use case for which you need to know the details?

Comment: Got it. Technically, I'm not a developer based on the google cast APIs, I'm a student and want to make a little self-research about new possibilities. My intention was to figure out the impact on performance and efficiency with various Codecs, or even different transmit protocols. I tried all kinds of means and read whatever I found on internet, but I cannot find materials talking about internal details, that's why I keep asking again and again.... Or probably the only possibility is to make through interviews and join the team in future...